# Let $a_n = \frac{2n}{3n+1}$, determine if {$a_n$} is convergent.

Tags: calculus

Let $a_n = \frac{2n}{3n+1}$, determine if {$a_n$} is convergent.

So what I did is I followed the definition of a convergent sequence which states that for any $\epsilon >0$ there is an $N>0$ s.t if $n\geq N$ then $|a_n-L|<\epsilon$

So using this definition, I came up with:

$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} a_n = 2/3$$

for any $\epsilon >0$ there is an $N>0$ s.t if $n\geq N$ then $|a_n-2/3|<\epsilon$

$$|a_n-2/3|<\epsilon$$
$$|\frac{2n}{3n+1}-\frac{2}{3}|<\epsilon$$
$$|\frac{-2}{9n+3}|<\epsilon$$

$$\frac{2}{9n+3}<\epsilon$$
$$\frac{9n+3}{2}>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$$
$$9n+3>\frac{2}{\epsilon}$$
$$9n>\frac{2}{\epsilon}-3$$
$$n>\frac{\frac{2}{\epsilon}-3}{9}$$

Hence there is an $N>0$ s.t if $n>\frac{\frac{2}{\epsilon}-3}{9}$ then $|a_n-2/3|<\epsilon$ thus I can conclude that the sequence is indeed convergent. I think that the way I did this seems correct and if it is not could anyone tell me why and where I might of went wrong, and also from the solution I was given they use a theorem known as the monotone convergence theorem to show that this is convergent. My question is how do you know when to use that theorem? and is it OK to use the definition of convergent sequence to prove that the sequence is convergent? or is MCT required to prove something is convergent for some sequences?

Comment: Your method is perfectly fine. You can use MCT, but it's not necessary. One often uses MCT when the limit is unkown, because in this case it's impossible to prove convergence by definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MCT says that if an increasing sequence, (decreasing sequence) is bounded above, (below) then its supremum,(infimum) is the limit.  **Your approach is fine**. Just note that:
$$
a_n = \frac{2n}{3n+1}
$$
$$
\frac{2(n+1)}{3(n+1)+1}-\frac{2n}{3n+1} = \frac{(2n+2)(3n+1)-2n(3n+4)}{(3n+1)(3n+4)}=\frac{2}{(3n+1)(3n+4)}>0
$$
So $a_{n+1} -a_n >0  \longrightarrow a_{n+1} > a_n$

So this is an increasing sequence. 
Now, we have that for all $n$,
$$
a_n = \frac{2n}{3n+1}<\frac{2n}{3n}=\frac{2}{3}
$$
So it's increasing and bounded above by $$\frac{2}{3}$$

Now, you've shown that the supremum of the sequence is $$\frac{2}{3}$$
So indeed, $\frac{2}{3}$ is the limit of the sequence

Comment: @user3412839 You're welcome. Good to have you here, nice question.